# make implicit rules don't work without command

Tags: makefile

I have a simple Makefile like this:

```
%.t1:   %.t2

%.t2:
    echo "t2"
```

When I type
    `make x.t2`
it works fine.  But when I type 
    `make x.t1` 
I get

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'x.t1'.  Stop.
```

If I modify the %.t1 target to say

```
%.t1:   %.t2
    echo
```

Then it works.  Why doesn't it work without a command?  I'm using GNU make 4.0 on Fedora 23.

Comment: Because there isn't a rule to build `x.t1`. What do you expect make to do with the `x.t1` target at that point? Why would you have a makefile set up like this? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: My understanding is that %.t1 matches any target that ends in .t1.  So that's the rule that I would want it to use, just like it knows to use the %.t2 target when I ask it to make x.t2.  My goal is to use the dependency specs as a form of declarative programming.  The example I gave is contrived, but with multiple dependencies and side-effects, this approach can be quite useful.

Comment: You didn't give a rule for `%.t1` you listed a prerequisite. It is a rule with no recipe. make doesn't like that. You can give it an empty recipe if you'd like though `%.t1: %.t2 ;`. You'd also want to mark it as `.PHONY` for this to work well. Can you provide a small reasonable example of what you are trying to do here?

Comment: You must be aware that `make` expects its targets to be *files* that it can create. There are exceptions to that (`.PHONY` targets and the like) but the principle of targets being files is really fundamental, e.g. it decides whether to run a rule by comparing file modification times.  If you want declarative rules in which all targets are non-files, use something else (e.g. Prolog).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pattern rule with no recipe does not add a rule, it cancels implicit rules. See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canceling-Rules:

> You can cancel a built-in implicit rule by defining a pattern rule with the same target and prerequisites, but no recipe. For example, the following would cancel the rule that runs the assembler:
>
> ```
> %.o : %.s
> ```

A semi-colon can be added to tell make that it has an empty recipe:

```
%.t1: %.t2 ;
%.t2:
    echo t2
```

Which yields:

```
$ make x.t1
t2
```