# gnu make - recipe to keep installed version of file aligned with a master version of file

Tags: makefile, gnu

So here's a Makefile to install foo.conf, based on a master copy called foo.conf.master. It installs it to the current directory rather than /etc, just for testing purposes:

```
all: foo.conf.copied

foo.conf.copied: foo.conf.master foo.conf
        cp foo.conf.master foo.conf
        touch $@

#  Recipe to tell make that it is okay for foo.conf not to exist beforehand. 
foo.conf:
```

So then create foo.conf.master:

```
$ touch foo.conf.master
$
```

and you're ready to test:

```
$ make
cp foo.conf.master foo.conf
touch foo.conf.copied
$
```

The point is that if I (with my "trusted" sysadmin hat on) modify foo.conf.master then make (possibly called by cron) will roll out the update:

```
$ touch foo.conf.master
$ make
cp foo.conf.master foo.conf
touch foo.conf.copied
$
```

But equally important: if I (with my "rogue" sysadmin hat on) modify the *installed* version then make will back out the update:

```
$ touch foo.conf
$ make
cp foo.conf.master foo.conf
touch foo.conf.copied
$
```

Woohoo.

Okay, so now the problem: obviously foo.conf isn't the only file I want do this for, so I need to change my static rules to pattern rules. Okay, that's easy: substitute foo.conf for % in targets and dependencies, substitute foo.conf for $* in the commands, and make a minor modification to the last recipe (which would otherwise become only '%:') so that it doesn't look like I'm trying to *cancel* a builtin pattern rule.

So clean up and create this Makefile:

```
all: foo.conf.copied

%.copied: %.master %
        cp $*.master $*
        touch $@

#  Recipe to tell make that it is okay for foo.conf not to exist beforehand. 
#  Nop tells make that I'm not *cancelling* a pattern rule here
#  (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315150/make-implicit-rules-dont-work-without-command).
%: ;
```

But this doesn't work:

```
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `foo.conf.copied', needed by `all'.  Stop.
$
```

The error message is misleading; it is really foo.conf that it doesn't know how to make, which can be demonstrated by adding the following at the bottom of the Makefile:

```
foo.conf:
        touch $@
```

But then that's a static rule again, which I don't want.

There are a couple more requirements I would also like to satisfy, which the above example doesn't demonstrate. These are:

- foo.conf should be installable anywhere in the filesystem (e.g. /etc/foo/server/foo.conf)
- foo.conf.master should be in a central directory, or subdirectly thereof, for all master versions, preferably without the '.master' extension (e.g. ~/poor-mans-puppet/master-files/etc/foo/foo.conf)
- foo.conf.copied should be in a central directory, not in the same directory as foo.conf (e.g. ~/poor-mans-puppet/timestamp-files/etc/foo/foo.conf)

After much googling, hair pulling, I'm asking here! Any ideas please? (PS: if copying Makefiles from here, remember to change indentation back to tabs.)

Mad Scientist below suggested an elegant static rule, but I really need it to be a pattern rule. The reason is that I need to hook extra dependencies in using rules:

```
all: <new-dependency>
```

rather than hooking them in using variables:

```
STUFF_ALL_SHOULD_DEPEND_ON += <new-dependency>
```

The reason for this requirement is for consistency with how other (non-%.copied) targets are handled in my very large Makefile.

However, based on Mad Scientist's idea, I tried the following, which didn't work, but perhaps helps somebody to help me:

```
all: foo.conf.copied

%.copied: %.master %
    $(eval FILES_FOR_WHICH_AN_EMPTY_RECIPE_ARE_NEEDED += $$*)
    cp $*.master $*
    touch $@

define GENERATE_STATIC_EMPTY_RULE
$(1):
endef

$(foreach X,$(FILES_FOR_WHICH_AN_EMPTY_RECIPE_ARE_NEEDED),$(eval $(call GENERATE_STATIC_EMPTY_RULE,$(X))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why you're using this extra ".copied" file?  Why don't you just use:

```
%: %.master ; cp $< $@
```

?

Anyway, you're running afoul of make's special rules related to match-anything rules (pattern rules like `%` that can build everything).  If you change your pattern so it's not match-anything, like `%.conf: ;` then it will work.  However you probably don't want to assume that all files end in `.conf`.

Alternatively you can use static pattern rules, like this:

```
FILES_TO_COPY = foo.conf bar.conf biz.baz

all: $(FILES_TO_COPY:%=%.copied)

$(FILES_TO_COPY:%=%.copied): %.copied : %.master %
        cp $*.master $*
        touch $@
```

and you don't need the extra pattern rule.

Comment: The .copied file is needed because I want to recopy the file if foo.conf.master is update *or* foo.conf itself is updated. Search for 'rogue' in the original post.

Regarding "you probably don't want to assume that all files end in .conf": indeed.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I dynamically generated static rules. The following pseudo-code hopefully makes the actual Makefile easier to understand:

```
if flag not set                   #  flag won't be set on first call
    prepare static rules
    set flag                      #  prevent running this clause again
    recurse!                      #  make invokes make
else
    include static rules
    do the normal thing
endif
```

Here's the real Makefile:

```
ifeq ($(MAKELEVEL),0)
all:
        for X in $(patsubst %.copied,%,$^); do \
            echo "$$X.copied: $$X.master $$X"; \
            echo "      cp $$X.master $$X"; \
            echo "      touch \$$@"; \
            echo "$$X: ;"; \
        done > Makefile.include
        $(MAKE)

#  The real dependencies on all are defined below, but while creating
#  Makefile.include, we don't want make to digress and start making
#  the dependencies; this pattern rule will stop it from doing that.
%.copied: ;
else
include Makefile.include
endif

all: foo.conf.copied
```

The outer make can be silenced by use of `.SILENT` and the `--no-print-directory` option (not shown above for clarity).

Here's the output:

```
$ touch foo.conf.master
$ make
cp foo.conf.master foo.conf
touch foo.conf.copied
$ touch foo.conf
$ make
cp foo.conf.master foo.conf
touch foo.conf.copied
$
```